# Is <audio> deprecated should we use AudioContext instead?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, html5-audio, deprecated

Is `<audio>` deprecated should we use AudioContext to create sounds instead?
Or does it mean `new Audio` is deprecated or both?

> Deprecated since Gecko 22 (Firefox 22 / Thunderbird 22 / SeaMonkey
>   2.19)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/Introducing_the_Audio_API_Extension

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `<audio/>` element is not deprecated. That document is about the Audio Data API which was once an idea competing with the Web Audio API for becoming the standard for doing audio processing in the browser. But ultimately the Web Audio API was chosen as a standard and the Audio Data API got deprecated. It was only available in Firefox.